# Spring Data REST - First 10 calls to DB are very slow

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

## Problem description

After launching my Spring Boot application, connected to a Postgres database via JPA/Hibernate and using Spring Data REST, the first 10 calls that are made via the REST API to the application are very, very slow (ranging from 5-10 seconds).

## Project setup and configuration

I have a parent "template" project, by which a generic domain model is provided to child projects. These are then made available in every subproject, including all other beans in the parent project.

The setup looks like this:

For the parent project:

1. My own generic parent POM (using spring-boot-starter-parent together with additional dependencies)

   | ...is parent POM of
2. *Parent project* (Spring Boot/Spring Data REST, providing the generic beans)

For the subproject:

1. My own generic parent POM (same as above)

   | ...is parent POM of
2. *Subproject* -> has *Parent project* as a dependency

## Expected and actual results

I've tried to create (via HTTP POST, using the REST API) several instances of the same entity in both projects. Using *Parent project*, the entities get created in about 0.1 seconds, consistently. But in *Subproject*, the first 10 - and consistently exactly 10 - HTTP calls (both POST and GET) are really slow, up to 10 seconds per request, for the exact same entity. Expected behaviour is to see the same speeds from the first call.

After these first 10 requests, performance is similar to the parent project.

I have no clue as to why this behaviour is happening. If anyone has a suggestion, it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by looking at the SQL queries Hibernate was executing. I was working with an InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS. Because of this - and as a lot of online documentation also mentions - there can be a serious drain on performance when dealing with a lot of entity types, which is the case in my situation by extending the base project. Too much UNION and JOIN queries had to be performed. By switching to InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE, it's working blazing-fast again!